# Why do I get hundreds of MBs of downwards data transfer on startup, esp. after a long time not using Ubuntu?

Tags: startup

I have massive downloads on startup, esp. after not booting for a while (typically 300-500 MB). I can see that from the preinstaled GPU monitor app (I don't remember its name). I think I've seen 1.3GB once. What can these be?

Comment: Do you have your system updates set to "automatic"?

Comment: BTW, welcome to Ask Ubuntu -- be sure to take the [tour] and read over the [FAQ] to get a better idea how Stack Exchange sites work.

Comment: They can be lots of things, but are more likely to be deb upgrades (Unattended Updates) and Snap updates. One of the key features of Ubuntu is it's built-in security, and those are two of the tools providing that security.